# Set LayoutManager on a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, kotlin

I have created a Fragment where I'm trying to implement a recyclerView and load a list. The problem is coming when I try to set the ***layoutManager***

Error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager)'
>   on a null object reference
>                                                                              at
>   com.gn.app.Fragments.StationsFragment.onCreateView(StationsFragment.kt:37)

I cant figerout what is wrong.

Fragment:

```
class StationsFragment : Fragment() {

    companion object {
        val TAG: String = StationsFragment::class.java.simpleName
        fun newInstance() = StationsFragment()
    }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater?, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        activity.title = getString(R.string.title_home)
        val view = inflater?.inflate(R.layout.fragment_stations, container, false)

        rcViewStations.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)

        val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(url)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build()

        val stations = retrofit.create(StationService::class.java)

        val call = stations.getStations()

        call.enqueue(object : Callback<ResponseStations> {

            override fun onResponse(call: Call<ResponseStations>?, response: Response<ResponseStations>?) {
                if (response?.code() == 200) {
                    loadData(response.body()?.stations)
                }
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<ResponseStations>?, t: Throwable?) {
                //TODO: Implement error response.
            }

        })

        return view
    }

    private fun loadData(stations: List<StationsItem?>?) {
        val items = stations?.map {
            it?.let {
                Station(name, long, lat)
            }
        }
        rcViewStations.adapter = AdapterStation(items)
    }
}
```

Utils

```
fun ViewGroup.inflate(layoutId: Int): View {
    return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(layoutId, this, false)
}
```

Fragment xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context="com.gn.app.Fragments.StationsFragment">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rcViewStations"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:behavior_overlapTop="30dp"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</FrameLayout>
```

item xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="10dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtStationName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
                android:transitionName="transitionTitle"
                tools:text="Name" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtStationDistance"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"
                android:transitionName="transitionDesc"
                tools:text="0.00 m" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtStationBikes"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"
                android:transitionName="transitionDesc"
                tools:text="12" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtStationSlots"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"
                android:transitionName="transitionDesc"
                tools:text="22" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtStationDate"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="end"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
                android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                android:transitionName="transitionPrice"
                tools:text="Date" />

        </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: read stacktrace: rcViewStations.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)  Attempt to invoke virtual method...on a null object reference. This means that your  rcViewStations is null on this line. To initialize it you should use findViewById

Comment: yep, I know it but in theory by using ***kotlin-android-extensions*** you can use ```rcViewStations.layoutManager``` instead too ```findViewById``` @ViktorYakunin

Comment: kotlin has source code for android-extensions, please try to understand how it works. You inflated a view and tried to work with kotlinx.android.synthetic references right away, but they are not there yet. So even in theory you can't do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the problem setting the layout inside this `onActivityCreated` what makes sense because the view is not created.

so the class looks like this:

```
class StationsFragment : Fragment() {

    companion object {
        val TAG: String = StationsFragment::class.java.simpleName
        fun newInstance() = StationsFragment()
    }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater?, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        activity.title = getString(R.string.title_home)
        val view = inflater?.inflate(R.layout.fragment_stations, container, false)

        return view
    }

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)

        rcViewStations.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)

        val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(url)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build()

        val stations = retrofit.create(StationService::class.java)

        val call = stations.getStations()

        call.enqueue(object : Callback<ResponseStations> {

            override fun onResponse(call: Call<ResponseStations>?, response: Response<ResponseStations>?) {
                if (response?.code() == 200) {
                    loadData(response.body()?.stations)
                }
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<ResponseStations>?, t: Throwable?) {
                //TODO: Implement error response.
            }

        })
    }

    private fun loadData(stations: List<StationsItem?>?) {
        val items = stations?.map {
            it?.let {
                Station(name, long, lat)
            }
        }
        rcViewStations.adapter = AdapterStation(items)
    }
}
```

Comment: I had the same problem. I saw your solution here and fixed it. So the problem was the activity that needs to be created. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

`rcViewStations` is null how the Exceptions says.
It looks like you are using the kotlin android extensions which uses `getView()` internally.
getView() can only return a value after onCreateView is finished.

You can either do all view manipulation logic in `onViewCreated` or accessing the RecyclerView by using `findViewById` on your newly created View from `inflater?.inflate(R.layout.fragment_stations, container, false)`